# JPA Find by restricted collection

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring hibernate with the Spring JPA repository interface.

In my model I've set up a classic two way one to many, and many to one for customer and addresses. The address has a field called "customer" which has the customer object, and the customer has a collection of Addresses in a field called addressBook.

```
//from Address Class

 @ManyToOne
private Customer customer;

// from Customer class

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "customer")
private List<Address> addressBook;
```

Note I'm only eager fetching at the moment because it wasn't working with Lazy fetching...

I want to be able to retrieve an address through the customer from the repository. How do I do this in code? Something like this:

```
 Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(customerId);

    Address address = customer.getAddressBook().findOne(addressId);
    // or maybe
    Address address = addressRepository.findByCustomerAndId(customer, addressId);
```

Comment: I don't understand which problem you have.. however this  `Address address = customer.getAddressBook().findOne(addressId);` is wrong, use repository...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the last should work:

```
 Address address = addressRepository.findByCustomerAndId(customer, addressId);
```

If you struggle with creating repository methods you can read the Spring Data JPA documentation. Especially [this table](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#d0e1520) is very helpful. If you need to create query on nested entity attributes you can do it as well as it is described [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html#d0e391).

Comment: Ok thank you, I'll keep going with this one. I was getting an error "couldn't find local variable customer". I read that section before on JPA nested attributes, but it seems to apply to the scenario of finding the "customer who has an address matching id", I need tofind the address from the customers address book. JPA seems really unintuitive, not being able to traverse foreign key relationships through an ORM is a bit primitive....I added an address to the customer's address book, and tried to save the customer - seems logical to me, but it didn't work either. Anyway I'll keep trying this.

Comment: Ok this works, the syntax ended up being:  Customer customer = customerRepository.findOne(customerId);

Address address = addressRepository.findOneByCustomerAndId(customer, addressId);

Comment: You could use addressRepository.findByCustomerIdAndId(customerId, addressId) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would provide a findAddress method on the Customer class:

```
public Address findAddress(Long addressId) {
    if(addressId == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Address matchingAddress = null;
    for(Address address : this.addressBook) {
        if(addressId.equals(address.getId()) {
            matchingAddress = address;
            break;
        }
    }
    return matchingAddress;
}
```

Comment: Not sure about this answer, it seems slow to iterate all the addresses when I already have both key values. I'm just trying to avoid the scenario of a customer modifying another customer's address.

Comment: You only need one key though (the address ID) as you already have retrieved the customer.